# Sending multiple values from form to controller with cakephp3

Tags: php, html, cakephp-3.x

I'm making a form to search my application for users with their name or email. Specifically, I am trying to make a search engine, but I don't know how to send two parameters from my form to my controller in cakephp3.

// In my controller

```
       $keyword =$this->request->query('keyword' );
     $users = $this->Users->findAllByFirst_nameOrEmail($keyword);
```

// In my form

```
        <?= $this->Form->create("",['type'=>'get']) ?>
           <?=  $this->Form->control('keyword'); ?>
           <button>Search</button>
        <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Comment: Please post your questions in English only.

Comment: I am making a form to search my application for users with their name or email, that is, I am trying to make a search engine, but I don't know how to send two parameters from my form to my controller in cakephp3.

Comment: What's not working about your existing code? It looks like it should be fine, as far as it goes.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add another argument in your method, here you are using `findAllByFirst_nameOrEmail`, Here you have two fields so you have to give two arguments. In your case you just can change your code

```
$users = $this->Users->findAllByFirst_nameOrEmail($keyword);
```

to

```
$query   = $this->Users->findAllByFirstNameOrEmail($keyword,$keyword);
```

Check doc OR condition again [Dynamic Finders](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#dynamic-finders)